# Prompt a User to Set Up iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

I am starting to implement iCloud, and I would like to prompt the user to set up iCloud account if he doesn't have it set up yet.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7819939/1445366

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9092142/347339).

So in your case it would be the following bit of code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=CASTLE"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: Yes it is: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/openURL:

Please consult the original question I pointed to for more on this solution.

Comment: Huh. Neat! Might be useful.

Comment: I thought the `prefs:` URL scheme was only available in iOS 5.0 and iOS 5.1 (and it was undocumented). Are you sure this still works?

Comment: @RazorSharp is correct.  This won't work in iOS 6.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question of how to *check* if the user has iCloud enabled.  Also, you need a space between `NSURL` and `*url`.